# how to compile emacs 22.3

Tags: emacs, compilation

I've recently made a Slax instalation with only the core program.
I used a copy of the live CD and ran a script to make hda1 bootable and then another script to use lilo to boot it... they were all in the CD... So it's like a big live cd on my HD and not really a full fledged OS.
Anyway I want to begin by compiling my own Emacs... Can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: This question is really not related to programming.

Answer (score 3):

The process shouldn't be too complicated. First, you need to download the source from http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/
Then, you untar the source with

```
tar xzf emacs-22.3.tar.gz
```

and cd into the newly created directory (emacs-22.3)
There, you run:

```
./configure
```

and then

```
make && make install
```

Read the INSTALL file for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To compile emacs 22.3, first download http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/emacs-22.3.tar.gz .  Extract the files to a directory, and then follow the instructions in the INSTALL file to install.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about how to compile it on a read-only filesystem:

1. If you have lots of RAM, you can mount a ram disk.
2. If you have a harddisk, you can mount the extra space.
3. You can look at something like `fuse` for more ideas.